# How to use protractor to console log a statement into the browser console?

Tags: protractor

I am using protractor to test my angular application.I would like to `console.log('Statement')` to the browser console. However when I do this this is directed to the console/terminal from which I invoked the protractor script.

How can I access the browser console and write into it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [executeScript](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.executeScript) to run any JavaScript in the current window.  You can pass a string or a function, I prefer the string version personally:

`browser.executeScript('console.log("hello")');`

Function version:

```
browser.executeScript(() => {
    console.log('hello');
});
```